# Creating a function to change values and output result

Tags: php

I'm working with a database table that is storing only integer numbers.
Like so:

```
id | value1 | value2 | value3
-----------------------------
1  |      5 |      4 |      3
2  |      3 |      4 |      5
```

It's stored that way for convenience, each number is supposed to correspond to a line of text.
The value 3 it's supposed to be "Ok", 4 is "Alright", 5 is "Awesome!", no matter the column, they all work the same.

I would like to create a simple function to automatically change those values into their corresponding text line, I know how to do it manually for each (just a simple `if(this){$var = "line of text";}`), but it'll be a waste of code and processing power doing that for each column, I have over twenty of them, I'm sure this could be accomplished with a simple function, but I've never done something like it, could you guide me through?

I'll use this code to get the values from the table (Joomla):

```php
$db = JFactory::getDbo();
$query = $db->getQuery(true);
$query->select(array('value1', 'value2', 'value3'))->from('values')->where('user_id = ' . $db->quote($user->id));
$db->setQuery($query);
$values= $db->loadObjectList();
foreach ($values as $value) {
    $value1 = $value->value1;
    $value2 = $value->value2;
    $value3 = $value->value3;
}
```

But this would return the values as they are in the table, just the integer, I would like to pass them through a function like `convertToString($value->value1)` for instance, that will return the corresponding text line.

Comment: If you know how to do it “manually” for one value, then where is the actual problem with wrapping that into a function that gets this value passed in as a parameter? Did you try anything at least here? This sounds really very very basic …

Comment: Joomla has features by which you can "translate" value in the view (in fact, if your site should ever need multilingual support, Joomla has language files that you set up to make this very clean).  I don't think you should be translating these values in the Model (where your query is appropriately executed) anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's important to show how the actual "line of text" are stored as well.

If it's a simple key-value array, where the line number is the key, and line of text as the value, then a simple array look-up should suffice. Here's a proof-of-concept:

```
/**
 * $text = [
 *     1 => 'blah blah blah',
 *     2 => 'blah blah blah',
 *     ...
 * ];
 */
$values = [];
foreach ($values as $value) {
    foreach ($i = 1; $i <= 20; $i++) {
        $propName = "value{$i}";
        $values[] = $text[$value->$propName];

        // If you want the indexes/keys in $values to also match the number:
        // $values[$i] = ...

        // If, however, you have declared individual variables for each line, eg, $variable1, $variable2, etc.:
        // $varName = "variable{$i}";
        // $$varName = ...
    }
}
```